# Error in using Using SSL with MongoDB Monitoring Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid3

I did edit the `settings.py` file in my agent installation from the help of http://mms.10gen.com/help/single/index.html#mms-requirements so that the `useSslForAllConnections value is True`
Now when i run python agent.py I get error like this

```
2012-12-19 15:09:37,209 ERROR Problem collecting non-blocking data from: gobingoo:27017 - exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prem/mms-agent/nonBlockingStats.py", line 56, in run
    monitorConn = self.mmsAgent.getDbConnection( self.hostKey )
  File "/home/prem/mms-agent/mmsAgent.py", line 109, in getDbConnection
    return pymongo.Connection( hostDef['mongoUri'] , slave_okay=True, ssl=True )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.4.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 180, in __init__
    max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.4.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 274, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
ConnectionFailure: SSL handshake failed. MongoDB may not be configured with SSL support.
```

What is the reason behind this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using SSL connections with MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/ssl/

Since this is not the case and you have turned it on in your agent MMS attempts to do a SSL handshake with the MongoDB cluster and fails.

You should set this flag within your agent settings file to false since you do not use SSL connections in your MongoDB cluster.

The setting you talk about is a specific subset for a certain scenario: http://mms.10gen.com/help/single/index.html#using-ssl-with-mms one which does not apply to you.

Comment: i already did cd /etc/ssl/
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out mongodb-cert.pem -keyout mongodb-cert.key
cat mongodb-cert.key mongodb-cert.pem > mongodb.pem   and implement also before fetching this problem from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/ssl/

Comment: This may sound dumb but did you ensure you restarted MOngoDB with the ssl options and not just made the cert?

Comment: without SSl features off also is it possible to view statistics related to your dbs when pointing them. My main problem is Host is working fine, status and hardware is showing statistics, In dbstats tab also all related dbs are shown perfectly but in their statistics no data available. How can i solve this. I think by using ssl it will show statistics of my related dbs.am i right or wrong i dont know.

Comment: No this is something different and not connected to SSL, this is another problem, so it shows the servers stats but it doesnt show the dbs stats basically?

Comment: Yes. It is showing ping information also which is latest. only lack is the statistics of dbs is not shown. Beside this all is working fine.

Comment: I gotta admit if this also doesn't work when you turn off SSL I am at a bit of a loss, hmmm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21379/discussion-between-regmiprem-and-sammaye)

Comment: when i turn off SSL then i am able to get all working except the statistics of my dbs. Is anything wrong or have to add something? as it shows all dbs name also properly but no data available in statistics

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, I have a full cluster running, with MMS monitoring right now and everything is running SSL, so I can confirm it works.  However, I enabled each host as SSL enabled individually rather than altering the agent config and restarting.  That is, method 2 here:

http://mms.10gen.com/help/single/index.html#using-ssl-with-mms

You may want to try that invdividual setting just in case

To test things out first, try using the `mongo` shell to connect to each member of the set from the host you are running the agent, with SSL and verify that the connection succeeds:

/path/to/mongo --ssl --host  --port

If that succeeds, you have verified that the agent should be able to connect, and that your MongoDB set up is working.  It would probably be a good idea at that point to file an MMS issue in Jira to troubleshoot further:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MMS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Later on i did that with http://mms.10gen.com/help/single/index.html#using-ssl-with-mms